# PHP session lifetime problem

Tags: php, session

I'm using PHP5 here. I have made a login system that check's the username and password against the records in the database. I want to use sessions to store the logged value. For example, when I reach the zone where I "log in" the user succesfully:

```
if($errors = 0) {
    $_SESSION['logged'] = "1";
}
```

The problem is that I want the `$_SESSION['logged']` to stay active for let's say 5 minutes so when I do a `if($_SESSION['logged'] == "1")` after this time to return false. Also, I would like to delete this session after the user closes the browser. Basically, I want a session configuration so that the user can safely leave his desk and when him or somebody presses refresh after 10 minutes or enters again after the browser has been closed, the session to be already removed, and the access to be restricted.

Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003001/automatically-re-direct-a-user-when-session-times-out-or-goes-idle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`session_set_cookie_params()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to change the lifetime of the session cookie. Note that by default, it is set to **`0`** which means that the cookie is set until the user exits the browser. You can do this in the following way:

```
/* Set to 0 if you want the session
   cookie to be set until the user closes
   the browser. Use time() + seconds
   otherwise. */

session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();
```

Then check for the last activity time, updated each time someone visits a page.

```
if(($_SESSION['lastActivity'] + 300) < time()) {
    // timeout, destroy the session.
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION);
    die('Timeout!');
} else {
    $_SESSION['lastActivity'] = time();
}
```

Comment: You can destroy the cookie, but often the session is still valid until the session is destroyed, which PHP usually refers to as the session being garbage collected.  The distinction only matters if you've got a user with a misconfigured - or malicious - browser, or their cookies were stolen/sniffed, etc.

Comment: **@Daniel Papasian:** This is why you die after a check of the timeout. The cookie only contains the session id (by default). There is no way for a malicious user to modify the `lastActivity` time, which uses the server time (so changing the client's time has no effect on that value).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting it to one, why don't you set `$_SESSION['logged_time'] = time();` and then check the time against time() in your application?

If you'd like to actually expire the entire session, the exact specifics can change depending on your session handler, but for the default session handler (and any other well behaved session handler) you'll want to check out https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Answer (score 1):

You can change the configuration setting [session.cookie_lifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie_lifetime), e.g. in php.ini or a .htaccess file:

> session.cookie_lifetime specifies the
>   lifetime of the cookie in seconds
>   which is sent to the browser. The
>   value 0 means "until the browser is
>   closed." Defaults to 0.

This means (I think) that you can't have both expiry based on a timeout and expiry when the browser is closed. So maybe the best bet is to keep the default and set your own timer in `$_SESSION` as others have suggested, thus rendering this answer pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions stay alive aslong as the user stays on your site. You will have to use cookies to set a specific timeout.

Comment: I've read about session.gc_maxlifetime once and how this sends the session to "garbage". I thought I could use something like this.. ?