# Apache/PHP application sessions timing out

Tags: php, apache, session

I am fairly new to PHP and am running an open source web application called GLPI.  We have several users that have the application open all day long and after a while they have to log back on the application.  Is this the Apache session timing out?  If so what is the default and how do I change it.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely the PHP session's lifetime.

Questions with solutions that might help you:

- [PHP session lifetime problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173524/php-session-lifetime-problem)
- [PHP : What is the default lifetime of a session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156712/php-what-is-the-default-lifetime-of-a-session)

it's impossible to tell where in your application you need to change or add this without knowing it, but you may be able to change the `session.gc_maxlifetime` setting in php.ini without touching the application at all.

Comment: there's no session_lifetime, should be session.gc_maxlifetime